# Find sequence for generating function $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{12}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I know that I should use partial fraction but is this really right approach, would not it be like 12 fractions? That power to 12 is something that is problematic for me. Can you give me some hint please?

**EDIT:** I forget to mention that formula for sequence should be withou infinity and sums, for examle: $a_n = 2n$ (and the sequence is made of coefficients that are at $x^n$)

Comment: Just apply the well-known binomial series. And this is already in the most reduced form in partial fraction decomposition - you'd basically get back the same expression if you tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider that:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}, $$
then differentiate both terms eleven times. You will get:
$$\sum_{n\geq 11} n(n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-10)\,z^{n-11}=\frac{11!}{(1-z)^{12}}$$
or:
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{12}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+11}{11}z^n .$$

Comment: @Superian007: I don't get it. This answer proves $a_n=\binom{n+11}{11}$. If you don't like it, prove that $a_n=\binom{n+11}{11}$ by induction. In any way, the coefficients will be always the same.